# Improve performance of 8million iterations over a dataframe and query it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a for loop of 8 million iterations, which takes 2 sample values from a column of a 1 million records dataframe (say `df_original_nodes`) and then query that 2 samples in another dataframe say (`df_original_rel`) and if sample does not exist then add that samples as a new row into the queried dataframe  (`df_original_rel`) and finally write the dataframe (`df_original_rel`) into a CSV.

This loop is taking roughly around 24+ hrs to complete. How this can be made performant? Happy if it even takes 8 hrs to complete than anything 12+ hrs.

Here is the piece of code:

```
for j in range(1, n_8000000):
    ran_num = random.randint(0, 1)
    ran_rel_type = rel_type[ran_num]
    df_ran_rel = df_original_nodes["UID"].sample(2, ignore_index=True)
    FROM = df_ran_rel[0]
    TO = df_ran_rel[1]
    if df_original_rel.query("@FROM == FROM and @TO == TO").empty:
        k += 1
        new_row = {"FROM": FROM, "TO": TO, "TYPE": ran_rel_type[0], "PART_OF": ran_rel_type[1]}
        df_original_rel = df_original_rel.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
df_original_rel.to_csv("output/extra_rel.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

My assumption is that querying a dataframe `df_original_rel` is the heavy-lifting part where the dataframe `df_original_rel` is also keep growing as the new row is added.

In my view lists are faster to traverse and maybe to query but then there will be another layer of conversion from dataframe to lists and vice-versa which could add further complexity.

Comment: profile the code to find the bottleneck. `append` is an expensive operation, besides this doesnt take advantage of pandas vectorised operations. cant you run a merge instead?

Answer (score 1):

Some things that should probably help – most of them around "do less Pandas".

Since I don't have your original data or anything like it, I can't test this.

```
# Grab a regular list of UIDs that we can use with `random.sample`
original_nodes_uid_list = df_original_nodes["UID"].tolist()
# Make a regular set of FROM-TO tuples
rel_from_to_pairs = set(df_original_rel[["FROM", "TO"]].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist())
# Store new rows here instead of putting them in the dataframe; we'll also update rel_from_to_pairs as we go.
new_rows = []

for j in range(1, 8_000_000):
    # These two lines could probably also be a `random.choice`
    ran_num = random.randint(0, 1)
    ran_rel_type = rel_type[ran_num]
    # Grab a from-to pair from the UID list
    FROM, TO = random.sample(original_nodes_uid_list, 2)
    # If this pair isn't in the set of known pairs...
    if (FROM, TO) not in rel_from_to_pairs:
        # ... prepare a new row to be added later
        new_rows.append({"FROM": FROM, "TO": TO, "TYPE": ran_rel_type[0], "PART_OF": ran_rel_type[1]})
        # ... and since this from-to pair _would_ exist had df_original_rel
        # been updated, update the pairs set.
        rel_from_to_pairs.add((FROM, TO))

# Finally, make a dataframe of the new rows, concatenate it with the old, and output.
df_new_rel = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
df_original_rel = pd.concat([df_original_rel, df_new_rel], ignore_index=True)
df_original_rel.to_csv("output/extra_rel.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```